# Почему не получается подключить css и js к html странице в Spring MVC проекте? Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Почему не подключаются стили и js к странице? При отображении страницы- у этих файлов получаю

> failed to load resource: the server responced with a status of 404

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sources/css/styles.css">

</head>
<body >
<h1>Hey there</h1>
<a href="/departments">click here</a>

<script src="/sources/scripts/initial_service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Структура проекта:

[image]

Web Config:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller"})
public class WebConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        bean.setSuffix(".html");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/image/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/image/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/main.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: а если указать такой путь - href="/styles.css" , что пишет?

Comment: @Александр
Пишет, что не найдено. Но ваш посыл я уловил. Необходимо установить путь /sources/styles.css
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для работы в конфиг было необходимо установить:

```
  @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/sources/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/");
    }
```

или на html страницах не использовать часть `/sources/`